# Proving a particular inequality between two sums of ceiling

Tags: inequality, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, provability

We have an integer $N$ and $k$ integers $n_1 \geq n_2 \geq  \ldots \geq n_k$.
We also have a random permutation $\pi$ which permutes the indices of $[1, k]$.

I would like to prove that we have the following inequality for any random permutation $\pi$:

$$\lceil N/n_1 \rceil + \lceil N/(n_1n_2) \rceil + \cdots + \lceil N/(n_1n_2\ldots n_k) \rceil \leq \lceil N/n_{\pi(1)} \rceil + \lceil N/(n_{\pi(1)}n_{\pi(2)}) \rceil + \cdots + \lceil N/(n_{\pi(1)}n_{\pi(2)}\ldots n_{\pi(k)}) \rceil$$

Is it obvious ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try induction (Idk if it would work, it is just an idea).

Comment: Thank you for your help @Masacroso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that for each permutation $\pi$ we have $n_1 \geq n_{\pi(1)}$, $n_1n_2 \geq n_{\pi(1)}n_{\pi(2)}$, and so on. From this it follows:

\begin{align}
\lceil N/n_1 \rceil &\leq \lceil N/n_{\pi(1)}\rceil\\
\lceil N/(n_1n_2) \rceil &\leq \lceil N/(n_{\pi(1)}n_{\pi(2)})\rceil\\
&\vdots \\
\lceil N/(n_1n_2\ldots n_k) \rceil &\leq \lceil N/(n_{\pi(1)}n_{\pi(2)}\ldots n_{\pi(k)})\rceil\\
\end{align}

Summing left sides and right sides gives the desired inequality.

Comment: Nice proof @Sil. I was trying by induction but this is lengthy. Thank you :-).

Comment: @Dingo13 You are welcome.